# How can I get my VS Code Java project to stop pulling in Gradle 7.1.1, when I'm already specifying 7.3.3 or 7.4.1?

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code

I checked out a Java project that works in someone else's VS Code environment, but it fails in mine.

Even though the distributionURL in my grade-wrapper.properties file is set to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip, for some reason both the 7.3.3 AND 7.1.1 folders are created under the .gradle directory, and VS Code attempts to compile using Gradle 7.1.1. But this fails because I'm using Java 17, which is incompatible with Gradle prior to 7.3.1.

I have another project that uses 7.3.3 just fine.

I'm at a loss here, because a search across my directory yields no instances of 7.1.1 once I delete the errant directory, and yet it keeps cropping up. Is there a cache or registry setting somewhere I need to be looking for?

Comment: Removing my user .gradle file (after rebooting to kill whatever program had a hold of it) did not seem to help.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA seemed to have no problem (downloading and) using the gradle executable I specified, and the code was able to compile. Still no change in VS Code. Maybe this is a problem with the "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" extension?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the source of the problem was, but after I installed the latest jdk (17.0.2), updated my JAVA_HOME environment variable, and removed all generated files in the local directory, it is now working with the gradle version specified in the wrapper. I wish I knew what the actual source of the problem was so that I could help students more effectively when they encounter a similar problem.

Comment: I tied to replicate the issue but I could not, I have loaded a project into VS Code and Gradle works.